# Image not showing up in IE8

Tags: html, css, image

On my site - http://appliedcodingtech.com/site/factory_automation_photos, an image towards the bottom does not show up in IE8, but it shows up just fine in FF and Chrome. What is wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like it's an issue with the image (corrupt or whatnot). Just opening the image in a new tab doesn't even work.  My advice is take a screen cap of it and save that as Twin_belt_transport.jpg and re-upload it.

Comment: I took a screen capture of the image and re-uploaded it and that worked.

Answer (score 11):

The broken image is a [CMYK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMYK_color_model) `.jpg`, which IE8 does not support.

Answer (score 4):

I think it is a corrupt image - I used Paint.Net to open the image and re-saved it, and now IE will display it.

Comment: +1 - Just finished doing the same thing and got the same result.

Comment: I just uploaded the file to picnik.com and saved it and then reuploaded it to the website, and it still doesn't work. Does Paint.net do something different than picnik.com?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the image is corrupted (applications may handle this in different ways) or is stored in a way that is not supported by IE. Try saving the image again using an image editor.

The problem lies in the image itself. IE cannot open it from disk either. It is indeed a jpg image (it has the 'exif' header), although I don't have the tools at hand to study exactly what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 1):

Good question.

It seems that the image file is corrupted. **Re-uploading it would definitely fix it!**

**But also some pointers**

1. Thumbnails are too big. Use different images for thumbnails and for
   view purposes. It loads slow and doesn't look professional at all :(
2. Your using .jpg and .JPG file extensions. For a more beautiful code,
   use only lowercase **.jpg**!
3. There are spaces in the filenames. Use **_** or **-**